# error when running any query in sql server management studio: the file exists

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I run any query in sql server management studio, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: The file exists.

Restarting SSMS didn't help. Neither did rebooting the machine. The only thing I found on Google was someone saying "report the bug to microsoft" :P

*(Windows XP Pro x64, SSMS 2005)*

Comment: uninstall and reinstall the client tools...

Comment: any query at all! Mitch, post that as an answer. I'll accept it and bite the bullet if nobody else finds something that works

Comment: Good reference becausse I had such issue and just cleaned temp files as in answers.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I've been struggling with this one for while and when I recently installed Toad for MySQL I got the same issue.

I installed sysInternals process monitor tool to try and work out which file was causing the issue.

The answer is temp files.

Both SQL server management studio and toad use a similar naming convention for their temp files.  Both use the temp directory under your user account in Documents and Settings.  In my case, there were over 60 thousand *.tmp files in that directory.

Watching the query execute through process monitor I could see the SQL IDE continually trying and failing to identify a temp file name which didn't exist until it finally gives up with a "The file exists" error.

The solution is simply to clear out the *.tmp files in your local settings temp directory.

Both SQL Management Studio and Toad for MySQL are now working fine on my machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was getting the same error (even though I do not have Toad installed). Deleting the `%TEMP%\Microsoft\F12\SQM` folder did the trick. I feel lucky I only spent half a day on this.

Comment: Another broad / cryptic error message by Microsoft solved by SO.

Answer (score 11):

Going further into Stephen's answer, the path would be:

- For Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Temp`
- For Vista and above: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp`
- Or simply paste `%TEMP%` into the Windows Explorer address bar to get the path.

I recommend this little plugin in case you can't access the route:

**Take Ownership**
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue with SQL Server 2012 running on Windows 8.1. As @Stephen mentioned, the issue is with the temp files but I couldn't find them in the location he mentioned. Solved the problem by running disk cleanup and directing it to delete Temporary Files.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared temp files although issue was not solved hence I uninstalled the software through revo uninstaller thus it cleared all the software logs and software related registry data. And after re-installing problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this question creating another folder on directory.
SSMS creates numbered folders anytime the user open a new tab on it.
If you're having the same trouble, just create a numbered folder on
C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp and SSMS will return this no more.