# SQL 2016 Live Query Statistics Error: "An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: One or more errors occurred."

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

I am testing out SQL 2016 Live Query Stats in SSMS and every time I try it I get the error "An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: One or more errors occurred."  and no result set is returned.  A co worker has tried it and it works fine for him anyone else had this problem?

**UPDATED**
To answer the questions raised.  This is the entire error that is returned to the message tab. To reproduce all you need to do is select Live Query Stats in SSMS 2016 and run any query and I receive this error.

Comment: That is not the total error,can you update question with total errors and repro steps

Comment: also version of ssms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error when running any query in sql server management studio: the file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683690/error-when-running-any-query-in-sql-server-management-studio-the-file-exists)

Comment: Note this also happens on SQL Server 2017 CU17, latest version of ssms. When using live query stats

Answer (score 3):

I've been encountering this error suddenly this week. I note that using Live Query Statistics executes successfully once, then fails with the referenced error on every subsequent execution. This may explain why co-workers were able to successfully execute the command.

My solution (workaround) is to not use Live Query Statistics and simply enable the Actual Execution Plan instead. I'd be grateful if someone knows what the root cause of this error is so that either option could be used as required.

Comment: This fix worked for me. I suddenly received this error after changing a simple parameter value in a really complex SQL Server 2014 query that had previously been running without a hitch. After turning off Live Query Stats, the mysterious error vanished.

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce the error.

Install the AdventureWorks2016 sample database. I actually used the AdventureWorks2016CTP3 copy.

Enable the Live Execution via SSMS 2016. Run the following query

```
SELECT
      oh.AccountNumber
     ,oh.Comment
     ,oh.DueDate
     ,oh.OrderDate
     ,oh.Freight 
     ,oh.TotalDue
      ,od.[SalesOrderID]
      ,od.[SalesOrderDetailID]
      ,od.[CarrierTrackingNumber]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2016].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] as oh inner join [AdventureWorks2016].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] as od on od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
```

I receive the following error in the results pane. I will keep digging to find out why this is happening.

```
(121317 row(s) affected)

(6 row(s) affected)
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: One or more errors occurred.
```

SQL Server 2016 Management Studio   13.0.15000.23
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 T-SQL ScriptDom   13.0.1601.5 
Microsoft Report Viewer for SQL Server 2016 13.0.1601.5 
Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2016  13.0.1601.5 
Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server 13.0.1601.5 
Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (x86)  13.0.3330.1 
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client     11.3.6518.0